# Fix image to bottom of div, clip top of image

Tags: html, css

I have a large image that I'm using as a splash image at the top of my site. The image width is 100% of the viewport, and the image gets clipped vertically depending on the size of the viewport (while maintaining aspect ratio).

Run the code snippet below, open the full page view, and resize your browser window to see what I mean. Alternatively, [here's a Codepen](https://codepen.io/justusthane/full/REJRgG)

```css
#logo {
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  I'm a div. I probably contain a logo and I take up 100px at the top.
</div>
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://justus.ws/silence.jpg">
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>And I'm some content. Weeeee!</p>
</div>
```

How I would like it to behave instead is to fix the image to the *bottom* of the div, and clip the top of the image as needed. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you!

**Edit:** I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- The splash image width is always 100%.
- The height is a *max* of 100vw - 200px (to make room for header div at the top and content below).
- If the full image can't be displayed, the *top* of the image gets clipped (rather than the bottom, which would be the normal behavior).

  - If the image shrinks (i.e. if the window is narrowed), the containing div height shrinks to match that of the image so there's not any wasted space above or below.

Answer (score 2):

I would set the image to position absolute with a bottom of zero.

Here is the code

```css
#logo {
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

#header img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  I'm a div. I probably contain a logo and I take up 100px at the top.
</div>
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://justus.ws/silence.jpg">
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>And I'm some content. Weeeee!</p>
</div>
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The problem with that is if you make the window narrower, you end up with a bunch of white space above the image. The div height needs to shrink to match the height of the image, and I'm not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert your image to `background` image, then set:

- `background-size: cover;`
- `background-position: bottom;` - position of background image will be centered at bottom

```css
#logo {
  height: 100px;
}

#header {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#header img {
  width: 100%;
}

.header__img {
  background: url(https://justus.ws/silence.jpg);
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  background-position: bottom;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  I'm a div. I probably contain a logo and I take up 100px at the top.
</div>
<div id="header">
  <div class="header__img"></div>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>And I'm some content. Weeeee!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Hai, thanks for the reply! Unfortunately this doesn't quite do what I'm looking for either - the header image needs to shrink so that the full image is shown when the window is narrowed as in my initial example.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, folks! Thanks everyone for your answers.

```css
#logo {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

#header img {
  width: 100%;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 200px);
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="logo">
  I'm a div. I probably contain a logo and I take up 100px at the top.
</div>
<div id="header">
  <img src="https://justus.ws/silence.jpg">
</div>

<div id="content">
  <p>And I'm some content. Weeeee!</p>
</div>
```